# cmake install: how to remove subdir prefix

Tags: cmake, installation

I have a library libA. Structure is the following:

```
libA
+ CMakeLists.txt
+ mySRC/headerA.h
+ mySRC/headerB.h
+ mySRC/moduleA/modA.h
+ mySRC/moduleB/modB.h
```

My lib compiles fine and afterwards I want to install it using this cmake code:

```
SET(Source_dir mySRC)
SET(LIB_NAME libA) 
...
INSTALL(TARGETS ${LIB_NAME} DESTINATION /usr/local/lib)
INSTALL(DIRECTORY ${Source_dir} 
DESTINATION /usr/local/include/libA
FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")
```

**Result:**

libA.a ends up in

```
/usr/local/lib/libA.a (which is fine)
```

Headers end up in

```
/usr/local/include/libA/mySRC/*
/usr/local/include/libA/mySRC/moduleA
/usr/local/include/libA/mySRC/moduleB
```

What is not what I wanted. **I want to remove "mySRC":**

```
/usr/local/include/libA/*
/usr/local/include/libA/moduleA
/usr/local/include/libA/moduleB
```

How can I remove mySRC from the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/install.html#installing-directories) says, you can prevent CMake from appending the directory name by following it with a trailing slash:

```
INSTALL(DIRECTORY ${Source_dir}/
  DESTINATION /usr/local/include/libA
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")
```

Comment: Source_dir already points to mySRC since I used "SET(Source_dir mySRC)" (see the to SET-calls above the INSTALL). I dont get why cmake is adding the name of the mySRC since I just want to install the contents

Comment: @Anonymous Re-written from scratch, sorry. I should really keep off SO today, I keep mis-reading questions ...

Comment: Indeed, it is all about the missing backslash... thanks